# Swift: JSONDecoder won't decode when struct has default array initialization

Tags: ios, swift

I'm decoding a simple structure and ran into unexpected behavior.

```
struct Contacts: Codable {
  struct Recipient: Codable {
    let name: String
  }

  let recipients: [Recipient]
}

do {
    let jsonData = SOME STING WITH VALID JSON
    let contacts = try JSONDecoder().decode(Contacts.self, from: jsonData)
}
catch {
}
```

This decodes just fine. If I do this simple change to the structure, it no longer decodes.

```
struct Contacts: Codable {
  struct Recipient: Codable {
    let name: String
  }

  let recipients: [Recipient] = []
}
```

Now JSONDecoder won't decode the exact same string. Why does the default initialization of the array cause the decoder to stop working?

Comment: Maybe because it is declared `let`and can’t be changed once it is initialized?

Comment: A `let` property can only be set once so if you're giving it a default value then the initializer generated by `Codable` can't set it again.  If you change it to `var` it will decode.  It will still fail to decode if the recipients key isn't present in the json though which is what I'm assuming you were trying to prevent

Comment: Added a custom decoder init and do `decodeIfPresent([Recipient].self forKey: .recipient) ?? []` to default initialize it..

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Let the decoder initialize the stuff unless you implement a custom `init(from decoder` with custom behavior. If instances of the struct are created without the decoder add an `init` method providing a default value.

Comment: Yep, 'let' was the issue--brain freeze on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to read:

```
struct Contacts: Codable {
  struct Recipient: Codable {
    let name: String
  }

  var recipients: [Recipient] = []
}
```

The issue (as described in the comments above) is that your initial declaration of the variable is immutable (meaning it cannot be changed after it is initialized).  So, if you declare the initial value for a `let` as `[]` then you cannot subsequently change it.  By changing `let` to `var` you are declaring the variable as mutable (meaning it can be changed) which allows you to both supply an initial value as well as change the value later.

Answer (score 2):

Your `let` here isn't a "default initialization." It's defining `recipients` as a constant with a specific, compile-time, value. If you want a default value, then you can create a initializer for that if you like:

```
struct Contacts: Codable {
  struct Recipient: Codable {
    let name: String
  }

  let recipients: [Recipient]

  init(recipients: [Recipient] = []) { self.recipients = recipients }
}
```

Generally speaking on this kind of very simple data type, I'd make `recipients` a `var` instead (see John Ayers's answer for example). It's much more flexible, while maintaining all the advantages of a value type. But in cases where you want a `let` constant with a default (rather than a single value), you need an `init`.